# How to make GPE see my war directory?

Tags: maven, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I already have a war directory created through maven and i would like to use that directory instead of src/main/webapp but the target directory is not seen by GPE .  Other than  project refresh i do not know what wlse to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **Default Output Folder** path from  **Java Build Path-> Source**

Comment: Plain and simple. Just the way i like it. Thanks